# Mysql how to put a limit on a table with join

Tags: mysql

I want to LIMIT `timber orders` query to 10 for pagination.  The problem i'm having is the LEFT JOIN `timber_order_products` is counted with the LIMIT.  The LIMIT should only apply to `timber_orders`.

```
     $data = $DB2->query("
     SELECT o.order_id 
          , o.order_status 
          , o.customer_method 
          , o.payment_method 
          , o.customer_notes 
          , o.order_date 
          , p.name product_name
          , p.price product_price 
       FROM timber_orders o
       LEFT 
       JOIN timber_order_products p 
         ON p.order_id = o.order_id
      ORDER 
         BY order_id DESC
      LIMIT 10
      ");
```

How do i LIMIT results only from a specific table?  The `LIMIT 10` should only apply to `timber_orders`.  I can't group by because i need the `timber_order_products` rows.

Comment: You may could `JOIN` on a temporary table created via a sub `SELECT`. In the sub `SELECT` limit the results to 10 and create a temporary table with the results. Then `JOIN` the original `SELECT` to the temporary table. I'm not familiar enough with the MySQL syntax though to say for sure so I'll defer to someone else.

Comment: I would suggest using GROUP BY and using GROUP_CONCAT on the 2 fields from timber_order_products

Comment: @user892134, In answer to your deleted question, amdixon's solution was wrong, and is going to lead to fundamental errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a subquery:

```
SELECT o.order_id , o.order_status, o.customer_method, o.payment_method,
       o.customer_notes, o.order_date,
       p.name as product_name, p.price as product_price 
FROM (select o.*
      from timber_orders o
      order by order_id desc
      limit 10
     ) o LEFT JOIN
     timber_order_products p
     on p.order_id = o.order_id
ORDER BY o.order_id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Interesting. Never knew how sub selects worked. Learned something new today. +1

Answer (score 2):

Avoiding using a sub query, I would use GROUP_CONCAT. Then the products name and price can be split off in the code that displays the data:-

```
SELECT o.order_id 
          , o.order_status 
          , o.customer_method 
          , o.payment_method 
          , o.customer_notes 
          , o.order_date 
          , GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('~', p.name, p.price)) AS  product_name_price 
       FROM timber_orders o
       LEFT OUTER JOIN timber_order_products p 
         ON p.order_id = o.order_id
        GROUP BY o.order_id 
          , o.order_status 
          , o.customer_method 
          , o.payment_method 
          , o.customer_notes 
          , o.order_date 
      ORDER BY order_id DESC
      LIMIT 10
```